# OpenGL light - Color doesn't change smoothly at one angle

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, light

I've created a scene in OpenGL + Python + Pyside. I've got a problem with smooth color changing when I am rotating my object and using lights.

Every side of my object with the same normal vector has an angle when the color of this side is just jumping from on to another. For other sides with other normal vector this angle is different.

I am not rotating the camera, I am rotating the object.

I've recorded a GIF that shows what I am talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFm5J.jpg

This is how I initialize OpenGL:

```
def initializeGL(self):
    self.qglClearColor(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(42, 11, 0))
    GL.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    GL.glEnable(GL.GL_CULL_FACE)

    if ENABLE_LIGHT:
        GL.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING)
        GL.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT0)

        ambient0 = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1]; 
        diffuse0 = [0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1]; 
        specular0 = [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1]; 
        GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, self.light_pos)
        GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT, ambient0);
        GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse0);
        GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPECULAR, specular0);

        glob_ambient = [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7];
        GL.glLightModelfv(GL.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, glob_ambient);
        GL.glEnable(GL.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        GL.glShadeModel(GL.GL_FLAT);


    GL.glViewport(0,0, self.width, self.heigh)
    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION)
    GLU.gluPerspective(40.0, self.width/self.heigh, 0.01, 10000.0);
    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW)
    self.initialized = True
```

This is how I draw the scene:

```
def paintGL(self):
    GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL.glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluLookAt(*self.eyePos.getEyePos())

    GL.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, 0)
    GL.glRotated(self.xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    GL.glRotated(self.yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    GL.glRotated(self.zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

    if self.scene:
        self.scene.renderScene()

    GL.glPushMatrix(); 
    GL.glLoadIdentity();
    GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, self.light_pos)
    GL.glPopMatrix()

    GL.glFlush()
```

I set a material this way:

```
(...)
GL.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON)                                         
GL.glColor4fv([0.25, 0.25, 0.35, 1])                              
GL.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_AMBIENT, [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1])   
GL.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1])   
GL.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SPECULAR, [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1])  
GL.glNormal3fv(self.Normals[n])
(...)
```

Light position is `[-100, 100, 200]`
Eye position is `[0, 0, 50];`
Object position is `[0, 0, 0]`
Object is 20 units wide and 20 units high.

How to get rid of this annoying effect?

Comment: Where do you set the model matrix?

Comment: @BDL Hi, I've updated my post. I hope it now answers your question.

Comment: @JD Does the behaviour still appear when you skip the specular component of the light? - `specular0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1]`

Comment: @Rabbid76 No, there is no such effect when I set specular to 0. I guess this effects is caused by 'point nature' of light?